# APScheduler. What is the best practices to shutdown schedulers with any non memory storage?

Tags: python, distributed-system, apscheduler

I need to run scheduler distributed to many machines and has one single point to store jobs. I use redis for this purposes and my code looks like this:

```
jobstores = {'default': {'type': 'redis'}}
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)
scheduler.add_job(...)
```

When I place jobs into scheduler and call `.start()` it add jobs in redis. But when I run another instance of my scheduler or when I stop current one and re-run it again, scheduler add more jobs in redis (doesn't do cleanup).

Therefore I have this question. What is the best practice to do such things?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `replace_existing=True` option while you are adding a new job for this kind of usage.

From the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#adding-jobs):

> If you schedule jobs in a persistent job store during your application’s initialization, you **MUST** define an explicit ID for the job and use `replace_existing=True` or you will get a new copy of the job every time your application restarts!